# Signaturepad clear property not clearing in modal-bootstrap dialog box

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I am working on signature pad dialogue box and for the dialogue box i am using bootstrap modal. In this activity when i click on complete activity a dialogbox should open asking yes or no on clicking yes a dialog box with signaturepad in modal body and clear button in modal footer.

the problem is when clicking on clear button from modal footer the clear method of signaturepad module is not working Any suggestions would be of great help

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {SignaturePad} from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';
import { ClickOutsideModule } from 'ng-click-outside';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent {

  @ViewChild('SignaturePad1', { static: true })signaturepad: SignaturePad;

  public signaturepadoption = {
    minWidth: 2,
    penColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
    canvasWidth: 250,
    canvasHeight: 300,
  };

  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  openSm(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true });
  }

  SignaturepadPopUp(longContent) {
    this.modalService.open(longContent, { scrollable: true, centered: true });
  }

  onClear() {
    this.signaturepad.clear();
  }

  saveSignature() {
    const base64 = this.signaturepad.toDataURL('image\png', 0.1);
    console.log(base64);
    const blob = this.base64toblob(base64);
    console.log(blob);

  }
  base64toblob(base64) {
    const bytestring = atob(base64.split(',')[1]);
    const stringtype = base64.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(':')[0];
    const size = bytestring.length;
    const saveString: any[] = new Array(size);

    for (let i = 0; i < bytestring.length; i++) {
      saveString[i] = bytestring.charAt(i);
    }
    const ia = new Uint8Array(saveString);
    return new Blob([ia], {type: stringtype});
  }

}
```

```html
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Are you sure You want to complete Activity?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">No</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="SignaturepadPopUp(longContent)">Yes</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #longContent let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="m-signature-pad">
          <div class="m-signature-pad-body">
              <signature-pad #SignaturePad1 [options]="signaturepadoption"></signature-pad>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClear()">clear</button>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="openSm(content)">Complete Activity</button>
```

Comment: can you try reproducing your issue in stackblitz

Comment: (click)=“SignaturePad1.clear()” should work?

Comment: @MikeOne no it's not working

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @SergioCano if you are still looking for the solution, please check out my answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because `ng-template` is not rendered yet and thus the signature pad will be undefined. A way I found to work around this is to create my signature pad in a separate component and then add that component to the `ngbModal`.

So in your example:

```
<ng-template #longContent let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="m-signature-pad">
          <div class="m-signature-pad-body">
              <!-- <signature-pad #SignaturePad1 [options]="signaturepadoption"></signature-pad> -->
              <app-my-signature-pad-component></app-my-signature-pad-component> <!-- In this component you add the above commented out line and then do your functionality for the signature pad there. -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClear()">clear</button>
</ng-template>
```

I found that with this approach, you are able to use the `ViewChild` and don't get the `undefined` issue.

Hope this makes sense!